# Keyword iterator for Java client library (AdWords)

Tags: java, api, google-ads-api

In Google Ads Scripts (JavaScript) you're able to get all your Keywords data with this code below

```
  var keywordsIterator = AdWordsApp.keywords()
      .forDateRange("ALL_TIME")
      .get();
```

I'm using the Java client library and it comes with some basic operations, one of those is *getKeywords* which recieve as parameter an AD_GROUP_ID and returns all the keywords in that AdGroup.

Since I have a lot of AdGroups, it takes a long time to process all the data. (I loop n times this method to get all the keywords of all AdGroups)

Is there any method or selector that allows you to get all the keywords of every single AdGroup in one operation as well as the AdWords Scripts solution?

**EDIT**

[getKeywords code](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/java/basic-operations#get-keywords-in-an-ad-group)

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

According to the [example](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-java/blob/master/google-ads-examples/src/main/java/com/google/ads/googleads/examples/basicoperations/GetKeywords.java), `AD_GROUP_ID` is optional and if is not specified, it returns returns keywords from all ad groups.